# Where clause in Codeigniter Query Builder Class

Tags: codeigniter, query-builder

I got in trouble trying to get data from two MySQl table.
In the first table I stored image filename; in the second table I stored info about each image; info are in two languages, en and it. Of course not all images in first table have info in the second one.
I'm trying to get images an info for a selected language in the following way:

```
$this->db->select ('
            tbl_images.image,
            tbl_infos.info
            ');

$this->db->from('tbl_images');
$this->db->join('tbl_infos', 'tbl_images.id = tbl_infos.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('tbl_images.id', $id);
$this->db->where('tbl_infos.lang', 'en');
```

Now...if the tbl_infos table has text, the query return correct data, but if no info are stored I get an error since no images are retrieved; if I remove the lang where clause I get the iamge if no info are stored...but I get images with info twice!!

I'm getting crazy and completely stuck on this...how can I fix this?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try this

$this->db->join('tbl_infos', 'tbl_images.id = tbl_infos.id');

Answer (score 0):

Silly me...I got fixed writing the second condition in the same JOIN row.
So, the following JOIN:

```
$this->db->join('tbl_infos', 'tbl_images.id = tbl_infos.id', 'left');
```

becomes:

```
$this->db->join('tbl_infos', 'tbl_images.id = tbl_infos.id AND tbl_infos.lang = "en"', 'left');
```